# Nodes, Type Definitions, how Null works (C programming language) C linked lists

Tags: c, null, linked-list

I am struggling to understand something with nodes in linked lists in C.  I am given a list of 6 nodes on paper, and I am trying to draw how the nodes change after a few different sets of commands.  The list starts out as follows (if a node is named, the name is listed right before it):

head[2, link]-->[4, link]-->P[6, link]-->[7,link]-->Q[8, link]-->R[9, link is null]

1st set of commands:

```
R->link = Q;
head->item = 11;
P = P->link;
```

head[11, link]-->[4, link]-->[6, link]-->P[7,link]-->Q[8, link]-->R[9, link]-->Q

Here is my first question:  When you assign R->link to Q, does it just point around itself to the Q node?

2nd Set of Commands:

```
P->item = head->item;
Q = NULL;
P = (P->link)->link;
head = R;
```

[11, link]-->[4, link]-->[6, link]-->[11,link]-->Q[NULL?]-->P R Head[9, link]-->Q Null?

2nd Question:  What exactly takes on the value of null in the Q node??  Does its link disappear?  How can P = (P->link)->link move along its link after it is set to null?  Now that Q is null, what is R pointing too?

My code for creating the nodes is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int item_t;
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef node_t* pointer_t;


struct node{
       item_t item;
       pointer_t link;
       };

int main(void){

    pointer_t head, P, Q, R;

    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->item = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: Yes, that operation creates a cycle in the list and will cause headaches later on. Actually, after the first set of commands, your list becomes:

```
head[11,link]-->[4,link]-->[6,link]-->P[7,link]-->Q[8,link]-->R[9,link]--+
                                                    ^-----------<--------+
```

Answer 2: Setting `Q = NULL` does not alter the list. You're simply modifying a unrelated pointer and not any link in the list. Your list is now:

```
[11,link]-->[4,link]-->[6,link]-->[11,link]-->[8,link]-->P,R,head[9,link]--+
                                               ^----------------<----------+
```

Remember, `P, Q, R, head` are all pointers which point to elements within the linked list, changing them only changes what they point to, they don't change the structure of the linked list.